# Can an illusionist be competitive in an average encounter?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, magic

I'm thinking of playing a sorcerous Illusionist in a DnD 5E campaign. There may also be a combat mage in the party. I was just wondering if clever use of illusions could be on par, combat-wise with a proficient regular wizard. We also have a hammery cleric. Are there any situations in which one is more effective?

Comment: We like to avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, as the hold on this question indicates. To avoid subjectiveness, you need to give us some measure of effectiveness. Is it damage per round? Total max damage possible? How many enemies they can effectively "control" to keep them off of the damage dealers? It seems like you're also discounting the value of an illusionist in social encounters- they can achieve their goals without doing a point of HP damage!

Comment: Who are you competing with, and why, in your party?  The title of your question suggests that you believe that the two player characters are in competition with each other within the party.  Is that how your party/team/player group plays?  Or, are you asking for an assessment of combat power comparison between an illusionist focused sorcerer and a wizard who specializes in ______ school.  (There are 8 in the PHB).  Is the wizard from the school of Evocation, Transmutation ... something else?

Comment: It heavily depends on both your cleverness and how open the DM is to ruling on illusions. If both are favorable, illusions can be extremely powerful.

Comment: Since we are speculating, IMHO in general Illusion is fairly weak at early levels, but it may become fairly powerful later. So if you want to go there, you need either good allies for early, a lot of RP-ing that allows to avoid combat, or something to buff him early.